# Dervative in $\mathbb{R}^1$ v/s derivative in$\mathbb{R}^n$ $n \geq 2$

Tags: derivatives

There is a fundamental reason of this? :
In $\mathbb{R}^1$, any smooth function can be expressed as the derivative of some other function. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, however, not every vector-valued function can ve expressed as the gradient of some scalar-valued function.

Comment: On a line there are only two ways you can approach a point, from the left and from the right. In higher dimensions, you can approach from many more directions which places more constraints on the function.

Comment: Do you mean to say "What is the  reason why vector-valued functions $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R^n}$ are not in general expressible of $F = \nabla g,$ for some $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a smooth function $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ A necessary (and also sufficient) condition for $F=\nabla g$ is that 
$$
\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j} = \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}.
$$
In the case of $n=1,$ this is trivial.